# What is “sh -c” and what does it do?

Tags: linux, python

I was checking running processes for a Python script I created and I saw `sh -c python Program.py` was running.

What is `sh -c` and what does it do?

Comment: Did you [see this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831847/what-is-the-sh-c-command)?

Comment: I just read the article you provided however could you explain in more detail execute as interrupted?

Comment: Another good resource is the `man` page for `sh`.  Say: `man sh`

Comment: I forgot to mention that i looked at the man page but still could not find a answer that fixed my confusion

Answer (score 3):

Reference: `sh` - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell

`sh` just like `bash` takes a `-c` switch followed by a command name, with the intent to execute the command and then exit. The remaining text after `-c python` (here) are parameters provided to `python` .

So, this is a way to launch python with an "environment" (as provided by `sh`), similar to starting python manually from `sh` .

Environment: `man bash` <kbd>enter</kbd> then type `/ENV` and <kbd>enter</kbd>.
*(hit `n` to see next, and `p` to se previous instances of ENV in the man page)*

More words: https://askubuntu.com/questions/831847/what-is-the-sh-c-command